# IE8 issue with $(".lor1").length;

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a code like below where

```
<script>
document.querySelector("#lor_show").innerHTML = $(".lor1").length;
</script>
```

lor1 value is from

```
<div class='lor1' id='unk'><td align='center'><font color='green'><b>UNKNOWN TYPE</b></font></td></div>
```

results go to

```
<td align='center' class=\"lor_show\" id=\"lor_show\"></td>
```

on Chrome everything works good but not in IE8 even when IE8 will work as DOC Mode IE8 Standard mode

Comment: Which version of jQuery, you're using?

Comment: i have this same results with 1.2.6 and 1.4.4

Comment: resolved <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> thanks Tushar

Comment: on IE8 with old jquery version results was 0 insted of number 5

Comment: Don't use font tags. They have been deprecated for years and years.  **Your HTML is invalid!** divs can not contain a td as a child.